# Enumerator value resolution

Tags: c, compiler-construction, enums

In which stage of the compilation do enumerator values get resolved?

Eg:

```
enum numbers
{
    ZERO,
    ONE,
    TWO
};

int main()
{
    int var = ZERO;
    return 0;
}
```

In which stage of the compilation does the token ZERO get replaced with 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum`s are not pre-compiler directives, so `ZERO` does not get replaced by 0. They are evaluated like structs, unions etc. at the compilation time.

Comment: Thats what at what stage of compilation does that get processed? Is it during syntax analysis or lexical analysis?

Comment: Likely during translation, which happens after those two.